# why is exception thrown when declaring a builtin Set class in TSUN editor?

Tags: angularjs, typescript, typescript2.0, typescript1.8, typescript1.5

I have installed TSUN on my centos 7 machine using the command. then i open the typescript interpreter using the command tsun from the terminal . when try to declare a set it is throwing the following error .

```
> let pets = new Set(["Cat", "Dog", "Hamster"]);

Cannot find name 'Set'. Do you need to change your target library?  Try changing the `lib` compiler option to es2015 or later.
```

any help is appreciated
thank you

Comment: why are you taging so many versions of typescript?

Comment: i asked a question , if you know the question answer it . dont ask another question

Comment: WOW, just trying to help you out. lol. It makes no sense to use all those versions when you are using just one....

Comment: thank you very much

Comment: error basically states the solution "Try changing the `lib` compiler option to es2015 or later."